# Changing contact us to secured in magento

Tags: xml, magento

I know in order to do this I need to add to the config file located in app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/etc/config.xml the following

```
<secure_url> 
<contacts>/contacts/</contacts> 
</secure_url>
```

below the

`<frontend>` tag

but if I wanted to create a module that depends on Mage_Contacts can I just create basically an etc/config.xml file that mimics the one in Mage_Contacts_Etc? Additionally it seems like overkill just to do that for such a small little change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can override it in another module. Magento combines all XML files into one large XML tree, so individual files are not a problem. You are also right that this isn't really worth an entire module. In projects I complete, it's common to have a project-specific module for odds and ends like this.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: So I can create only the etc/config.xml that depends on Mage_Contacts_Etc and be done with it instead of creating a list of files that do the exact same thing. Basically I am trying to avoid just copying the app/core/Mage/Contacts with all the extra files Helper, Model, controllers, etc and just work only with app/local/Name/Modulename/etc/config.xml and achieve the same things as adding `<secure_url>  
<contacts>/contacts/</contacts>  
</secure_url>` in the core file

Comment: As to whether the config segment will work, I can't say, but the strategy of adding other XML files, it will combine as you intended.